# Syncano Android SDK - Check if user is logged in

Tags: android, syncano

I login using

```
Syncano.getInstance().loginSocialUser()
```

How I can check if user is logged in? It would be nice to have not asynchronous value of that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

After your call, you get a Response. If isSuccess() returns true, you are logged in. You also get a user object in a Response.
After this kind of successful request user key should be set, so you can check it with this code.

```
return !(getUser() == null || getUser().getUserKey() == null || getUser().getUserKey().isEmpty());
```

edit

In latest version of library there is a new method:

```
syncano.isUserLoggedIn()
```